# Binarytree delete node function isn't working in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I made a binary tree with python. `deleteNode` function is not working right. I want to make a function that delete node and after delete tree works properly. 
Now when I try to delete node that is in the tree, the wrong node were deleted.  Could you help me how to edit the code?

```
import math
class MyCompleteTree:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.arr = []
        self.arr.append(None)
        self.count = 0

    def isEmpty(self):
        if (self.count == 0):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def addNode(self, item):
        self.arr.append(item)
        self.count = self.count + 1

    def getHeight(self):
        return int(math.log2(self.count)) +1

    def preorder(self, index):
        if(index <= self.count):
            print(self.arr[index], end=' ')
            self.preorder(index * 2)
            self.preorder(index * 2 + 1)

    def inorder(self, index):
        if(index <= self.count):
            self.inorder(index * 2)
            print(self.arr[index], end=' ')
            self.inorder(index * 2 + 1)

    def inorderFromRoot(self):
        self.inorder(1)

    def postorder(self, index):
        if(index <= self.count):
            self.postorder(index * 2)
            self.postorder(index * 2 + 1)
            print(self.arr[index], end=' ')

    def printLeafNode(self, index):
        visit = False
        if (index * 2 <= self.count):
            visit = True
            self.printLeafNode(index * 2)
        if (index * 2 + 1 <= self.count):
            visit = True
            self.printLeafNode(index * 2 + 1)
        if visit == False:
            print(self.arr[index], end=' ')

        def deleteNode(self, item):
    if self.count > 1:
        if item in self.arr:
            self.item  = None
            self.count = self.count - 1
            print(item, "Deleted")
        else:
            print("No nodes were found in the tree")
    else:
        print("Tree is empty")
```

Comment: Why would `self.arr == item` ever be true? `self.arr` is a list of all the nodes, `item` is one item/node. Those can't be equal.

Comment: So do I have to add 'search function' for 'delete function'? or are there simple things to find certain nodes in array?

Comment: I edited code, but now there is another problem. The 'deleteNode' function deleted wrong node. Somebody can help?